# Power Automate flow - substring Expression with condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, formula, table

i have big trouble with simple expression with substring.

My goal is merge two sharepoint list to one excel table. And problem is when value is empty that flow crash.

is possible create expression with `If` statemant, when value is empty, do nothing ?

`String`

```
1980034 - John Wick
```

`expression result:`

```
1980034

{
  "id":@{substring(item()?['listItem1'],0,indexOf(item()?['listItem1'],'-'))}
}
```

Expression works, but when value missing flow crash

Comment: In which action you are using this expression? What should be the default value for `id` if expression returns empty result?

Comment: when listItem is ````NULL```` i need ````if```` statement to do nothing, when is not null do substring

Comment: ````ID```` is only name of column in table

Comment: Data operation ````Select````, From sharepoint list and JSON Map

Comment: Can you try using either of these expression? `if(empty(item()?['listItem1']), '', substring(item()?['listItem1'],0,indexOf(item()?['listItem1'],'-')))`

Comment: ``if(empty(item()?['listItem1']), null, substring(item()?['listItem1'],0,indexOf(item()?['listItem1'],'-')))``. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: works! thank you so much

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using either of these expressions:

```
if(empty(item()?['listItem1']), '', substring(item()?['listItem1'],0,indexOf(item()?['listItem1'],'-')))
```

**OR**:

```
if(empty(item()?['listItem1']), null, substring(item()?['listItem1'],0,indexOf(item()?['listItem1'],'-')))
```